# I don't know why the core modules in node js are not being recognized within my project using IntelliJ Idea (2016)

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I keep getting the error: Cannot find module 'serve-favicon.' This error occurs not just for serve-favicon but for all core modules which also includes 'body-parser', 'cookie-parser', etc.  I am using IntelliJ IDEA (version: 2016).  I already enabled the Node.js Core library, and I have been able to use core modules in other projects successfully.  What is different about this project however, is that I pulled it from github.  Do I need to install another plugin? If yes, which one? Do I need to add another package?

Answer (score 0):

serve-favicon, body-parser, cookie-parser are not node.js core modules.

You will need to install these dependencies from npm registry. To install these dependencies, you will need to run

```
npm install <package-name> --save
```

If you have pulled the project from github, chances are there will be a package.json file with a list of dependencies. In that case, all you need to do is run `npm install` from the project folder.